# How to implement progressive download in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, progressive-download

I need to provide music download service and I want to play it on Android, but it needs progressive download if I don't want to download the whole file before palying, I search it on Google but get nothing about implementation but some configuration about IIS, I'm using WAMP on my PC , what should I do?

More precisely , How could I play the music while downloading it from my server? It seems I need implement something thing different on my server.

Comment: Are you looking for chunked download?

Comment: if u willing to do it with PHP you can read 20% or 10% of mp3 file size

Comment: "Progressive" typically just means that the download, well, *progresses*. The file is simply being downloaded from start to finish, and probably played at the same time. That is opposed to "adaptive", in which the server will adapt to the download capacity of the client and send higher or lower bit rates and can switch between rates on the fly.

Comment: It seems you want to implement the `Range` http header. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Comment: …Or are you llooking for media streams?

Comment: I cant immagine why you're using both IIS and WAMP. PHP over IIS is different from PHP over WAMP (as WAMP goes with Apache)

Comment: And another thing: are you going to listen to streaming music through Android application (Java) or Android Browser (JavaScript+embed)?

Comment: For more precisely How Could I play the music while downloading the file from my server on Android ? .Yes I know media streams and Range, I mean I want some form like how youtube play the media, and from my search I need progressive download for the mediaplayer of Android APP. And I know apache is different from IIS, I just make an example.